# How to understand LinkedList?

Tags: java

An code instance of expressing the characters of LinkedList:

```
public class SimpleLinkedListTest {
    private class Node{
        public Node(Object o) {
            this.o = o;
        }
        Object o;
        Node next;
    }

    private Node first;

    public void add(Object elem){
        Node node = new Node(elem);
        if (first == null) {
            first = node;
        } else {
            append(node);
        }
    }

    private void append(Node node){
        Node last = first;
        while(last.next != null){
            last = last.next;
        }
        last.next = node;
    }
}
```

The instance describes the "Chain characteristic" to encapsulating new Objects,how can I understand the "append" method in it?And what is the exact 
"encapsulating process" LinkedList type performs?

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article about linked lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinkedList has two pointers first and last Node.

```
public class LinkedList<E>
    extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
    implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    transient int size = 0;

    transient Node<E> first;

    transient Node<E> last;
```

And Node class has two pointers next and previous:

```
private static class Node<E> {
        E item;
        Node<E> next;
        Node<E> prev;

        Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
            this.item = element;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }
```

Now when you add new element to the end of list it takes last Node and uses its next reference to link it to new node that contains your element:

```
void linkLast(E e) {
        final Node<E> l = last;
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (l == null)
            first = newNode;
        else
            l.next = newNode;
        size++;
        modCount++;
    }
```

The same happens when you add element to beginning of list but this time it goes to `Node first` pointer.

And when you want to remove element it assigns null to `Node next` pointer of `Node` class.